# Move Drupal site from localhost to remote production server

Tags: 7, migrations

I want to move my Drupal 7 site to a remote server. I searched the Internet for a solution, but the information I found were cluttered. Can someone care to write step-by-step how-to or provide a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend a lot on the production server environment, and other factors.

Basically, you just copy the database to the server (along with perms), the Drupal filesystem (perms,  etc),  and point your web server at the correct directory in the filesystem.

Provide more information for a more detailed reply.

Comment: Accepting it to improve my aceept-rate. :)

Comment: You might need to update the $base_url and database configuration in the sites/default/settings.php

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this steps and move your site to production server:
On your local site

1. Install [Backup and migrate](http://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate), which will take the backup of the database (**admin/config/system/backup_migrate**).
2. Install [Backup and migrate files](http://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_files) which will enable you to take a backup of your public files in the directory defined at *admin/config/media/file-system*.

On the production server

1. Install fresh copy of Drupal.
2. Copy the modules and themes from localsite's *sites/all/modules* and *sites/all/themes* to the respective folders on the fresh install of dev server.
3. Enable the Backup and migrate module and backup and migrate files module.
4. Go to **admin/config/system/backup_migrate/restore** and restore the backed up database and public files which you exported at your local site.